# Ошибка "'NoneType' object is not iterable" при работе программы

Tags: python, математика, числа

программа находит максимальное доступное избыточное число в диапазоне делителей от h до 2, выводит делимое и (sum-делимое). почему появляется ошибка?

> ```
> !!dividers_sum = sum(number_dividers)
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
> ```

```
from math import (
    sqrt,
    ceil
)
def dividers(number):
    dividers_list = set()
    dividers_list.add(1)

    for divider in range(2, ceil(sqrt(number))):
        if number % divider == 0:
            dividers_list.add(divider)
            dividers_list.add(number//divider)
        return (list(dividers_list))
def abundant(h: int):
    for number in range(h, 1, -1):
        number_dividers = dividers(number)
        dividers_sum = sum(number_dividers)

        if dividers_sum > number:
            return [[number], [dividers_sum - number]]
h = int(input())
print(abundant(h))
```

Comment: Отступы проверьте

Answer (score 2):

Вам очень нравятся списки, не правда ли?    (Мне тоже...)    И вообще скобки. :-)

Но вы усложняете себе жизнь, стараясь переводить все в списки и скобки не экономить...

Потому *я упростил ваш код в двух местах* - в одном из них была **ваша единственная ошибка** — не подходящий отступ.

Из-за него ваша команда `return ...` не выполнилась. Потому функция `dividers()` по умолчанию возвращала значение `None` (типа `NoneType`).

```
from math import (
    sqrt,
    ceil
)

def dividers(number):
    dividers_list = set()
    dividers_list.add(1)

    for divider in range(2, ceil(sqrt(number))):
        if number % divider == 0:
            dividers_list.add(divider)
            dividers_list.add(number//divider)
    return dividers_list                           # здесь была ошибка в отступе; 
                                                   # не нужно конвертировать в список :-)
def abundant(h: int):
    for number in range(h, 1, -1):
        number_dividers = dividers(number)
        dividers_sum = sum(number_dividers)

        if dividers_sum > number:
            return number, dividers_sum - number   # не нужно никаких скобок :-)

h = int(input())
print(abundant(h))
```

---

Пример выводов:

- для числа 99:    `(96, 60)`
- для числа 32:    `(30, 12)`
- для числа 16:    `(12, 4)`
- для числа 12:    `(12, 4)`
- для числа 10:    `None`